# How do I get the frame number that a grease pencil keyframe is on?

Tags: python, keyframes, grease-pencil

So I'm writing an addon, that's honestly getting a little bit of scope creep. But as of right now I'm having trouble finding a way to get not only the grease pencil keyframes, but which frame they're on. I've combed over the documentation and even spent a few hours using the python console's auto complete to see if there's a way to just get some lousy frame numbers.

Any and ALL insight is appreciated!

Comment: according to https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilLayer.html#bpy.types.GPencilLayer.active_frame
you should try layer.active_frame which retruns the frame currently displayed on a defined layer.
hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Every frame has a `frame_number` property:

```
for i in bpy.data.grease_pencils['Stroke'].layers['Lines'].frames:
    print(i.frame_number)
```

And for future reference, it's sometimes easier to find stuff by looking at the Data API in the outliner, rather than using the console's autocomplete (or the documentation for that matter).